# SQL Dataadapter refuses to update DB from Dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, sql-update, dataset

So i create this Dataset ds and add a row to the only table via addrow("THIS","BLOWS",0) somwhere else.

A datagridview shows me that the adding a row actually works but it refuses to update the actual mySQL database. It's like the updatesdb() method isn't even there. Where is my mistake?

```
class Mitarbeiterdb{
    static MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("***");
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mitarbeiter.mitarbeiter;", con);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public void setDataSet(){
        da.TableMappings.Add("table0", "Mitarbeiter");
        da.Fill(ds);  
    }


    public void addrow(string a,string b,int i){
        con.Open();
        DataRow tmprow;
        tmprow = ds.Tables[i].NewRow();
        tmprow[1] = a;
        tmprow[2] = b;
        tmprow.EndEdit();
        ds.Tables[i].Rows.Add(tmprow);
        updatedb();
        con.Close();
    }

    public void updatedb() {
         MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
         da.Update(ds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ADO is not quite smart enough to update on it's own, you need to set your own update statement and fill it with the values its going to update.

da.UpdateCommand = ....

Here's a link to a simple usage...

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UpdatetableusingSqlDataAdapter.htm

Answer (score 0):

In your updatedb() method you are missing .AcceptChanges();

```
public void updatedb() {
     MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
     da.Update(ds);
     da.AcceptChanges();
}
```

For more information read [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzb1zw3x.aspx)